# Make snapshot of VLCMediaPlayer (MobileVLCKit)

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, vlc, video-processing

I'm working on an app, showing stream video (by `rtmp`). I've started to use `MobileVLCKit` for it. I need a function that will make a snapshot of video. I have tried the built-in function

```
    func saveVideoSnapshotAt(path: String!, withWidth: UInt32, andHeight: UInt32)
```

But it doesn't work. That's what support have written about it on `videolan` forum:

> "*This method is OS X only. While it is exposed on iOS (what it should
>   not be, I agree), it won't work on mobile devices*."

Then I tried to use standard `iOS` functionality:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!
    var mediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()
    if let url = NSURL(string: "rtmp://someurl") {
        let media = VLCMedia(URL: url)
        mediaPlayer.media = media
        mediaPlayer.drawable = videoView
        mediaPlayer.play()
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(videoView.frame.size);
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        print("Couldn't get context")
        return
    }
    videoView.layer.renderInContext(context)
    guard let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

In result I get only `UIView` background screenshot, not video in it. Does anyone know if there is any solution or at least which direction I should keep searching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was simpler than i thought.

```
    let size = mediaPlayer.drawable.frame.size

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

    let rec = mediaPlayer.drawable.frame
    mediaPlayer.drawable.drawViewHierarchyInRect(rec, afterScreenUpdates: false)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Hi mediaPlayer.drawable is Any , it does not have frame. How to solve it?

Comment: @famfamfam, probably it was `UIView` or its subclass back in when I found the solution. First idea came to my mind without looking into code is to optionally cast it to `UIView`. Like that: `guard let drawable = mediaPlayer.drawable as? UIView else { return }`

Comment: @famfamfam according to property description, `drawable` _can be any UIView or NSView or instances of VLCVideoView / VLCVideoLayer if running on macOS_, so you can get size from view that you set drawable.

Comment: yeah. i just convert it to UIView then it work. (mediaPlayer.drawable as! UIView).frame

Answer (score 0):

Did you add delegate for mediaPlayer in your code like this
https://github.com/maknapp/vlckitSwiftSample/blob/master/vlckitSwiftSample/ViewController.swift

Comment: Yes. I just didn't want to write the whole code here. I make all actions with videoView when video is loaded and playing.